# Properly stagger an FFT? How to handle output data (Have highs weigh as much as lows?)

Tags: fft, audio, dft

I'm new to audio processing so I'm mostly running into problems with not being able to properly google something. Sorry.

Basically I want to create something like an equalizer (just visually without interaction and modulation for now). I got my FFT working in Unity and am now getting the ampitudes of each frequency for a given sample range (2048) at a certain time.

Now I think my problem is that my frequencies aren't staggered (right word?) when displaying them. Resulting in 31 bars that are basically not moving and one bar, the one with the low frequencies, moving a bunch.

What I want to achieve is something like this:
[image]

How would I go about to display my frequency information like that, with half of the room for 1 - 500 hz and the rest staggered from 1 to 20k?

I guess this is a logarithmic function. But if I just use "Mathf.Log()" on all the data points my EQ just explodes and isn't displaying anything properly.

Is there a proper way to go about this?
Especially how can I have the high frequency values > 10k be "weighing" as much as the lower ones?

And what words should I use in these contexts so that I can better search for my next question myself?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you intending on using the FFT to display the spectrum of audio data or are you intending on using it to modify the spectrum?

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson I just want to display spectrum data accurately. When I'm comparing my FFT implementation to the way my equalizer looks in the DAW they look vastly different. A simple synth at C8 more or less fills my whole spectrum while it has almost no lows in the DAW.

Comment: okay, well that display looks like the frequency response of a parametric EQ filter.  you don't need, nor want an FFT doing that because you would have to compute the impulse response first.  or it can be the ratio of two FFT magnitudes, if it's a IIR with a rational function as a transfer function.